# Удаление узла бинарного дерева си

Tags: c, дерево

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFF 256

typedef struct node {
    char *pnomber;
    int count;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} Node;

Node *AddNode(Node *Root, char *w) {
    int cond;
    if(Root == NULL) { 
        Node *Root = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        Root->count = 1;
        Root->pnomber = strdup(w);
        Root->left = Root->right = NULL;
        return Root;
        } else if((cond = strcmp(w, Root->pnomber)) == 0) {
            Root->count++;
        } else if(cond < 0) 
            Root->left = AddNode(Root->left, w);
        else
            Root->right = AddNode(Root->right, w);
    return Root;
}

Node *PrintWood(Node *Root) {
    if(Root != NULL) { 
        PrintWood(Root->right);
        printf("pnomber-->%s, count-->%d\n", Root->pnomber, Root->count);
        PrintWood(Root->left);
    } else return 0;
}

Node *SearchCount(Node *Root) {
    Node *SC = Root;
    
    if(SC == NULL) {return SC;}
    else { 
        if(SC->count >= 2)
            printf("pnomber-->%s, count->%d", SC->pnomber, SC->count);
            //printf("\n");
        return SearchCount(SC->left);
        return SearchCount(SC->right);
    }
}

Node *RootDelete(Node *Root) {
    Node *LM = NULL; // Локальный минимум
    Node *SN = NULL; // Найденый узел
    Node *TMP = NULL;
    SN = SearchCount(Root); //Удаляемый элемент 
    if(SN == NULL) return NULL; // Дерево пустое
    if(SN != NULL) { // Дерево не пустое
        if((SN->left == NULL) && (SN->right == NULL)) { // Нет ответвлений
            free(SN);
            return NULL;
        } else if(SN->left == NULL) { // Есть только RIGHT потомок
            TMP = SN->right; // TMP правый для SN 
            free(SN); // Стираем старый SN 
            return TMP;
        } else if(SN->right == NULL) { // Есть только LEFT потомок
            TMP = SN->left; // TMP левый для SN
            free(SN); // Стираем старый SN 
            return TMP;
        } else if((SN->left != NULL) && (SN->right != NULL)) { // Есть обе ветки
            LM = SN->right; // Перезаписываю  на правый потомок LM(лм стал правым для сн)
            //Node *PAR = SN; // Задаем родителя для LM
            while(LM->left != NULL) {
                //PAR = LM;
                LM = LM->left; // Влево до упора находим минимум
            }
            SN->pnomber = LM->pnomber; // Меняем значение узла на занчение лок мин
            SN->count = 1; // Значение счетчика приводим к единице
            SN = LM; // Перезаписываем самый малый элемент на место того, котор надо удалить
            //LMM = PAR;
            printf("pnomberSN-->%s, count-->%d\n", SN->pnomber, SN->count);
            printf("\n");
            printf("pnomberLM-->%s, count-->%d\n", LM->pnomber, LM->count);
            printf("\n");
            free(LM); // Стираем старый LM
            return SN; // Возвращаем новое значение верщины 
            
        } 
        //free(SN);
    }
} 
/*
void DeleteWood(Node *Root) {
    if(Root != NULL) { 
        DeleteWood(Root->left);
        DeleteWood(Root->right);
        free(Root);
    }
} 
*/
int main() {
    const char *text = "Number.txt";
    Node *Root = NULL;
    char LineBuffer[BUFF];
    char*p;
    FILE *fp = fopen(text, "rb");
    if(!fp){
        printf("file not open\n");
        return -1;
    } 
    while(fgets(LineBuffer, sizeof(LineBuffer), fp)) {
        if(p = strchr(LineBuffer, '\n')) *p = 0;
        Root = AddNode(Root, LineBuffer);
    }
    PrintWood(Root);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    SearchCount(Root);
    printf("\n");
    RootDelete(Root);
    printf("After delete------\n");
    PrintWood(Root);
    //DeleteWood(Root);

    return 0;
}
```

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как работает функция удаления узла из дерева, пробовал несколько вариантов,ничего не выходит.Функция должна удалять из дерева все элементы, количество которых в файле - два и более:(

Comment: Так в ней же всё комментариями написано. Каждый шаг. Что ещё тут можно пояснить? А о каких элементах из каких файлов идет речь? Функция работает просто - выбирается узел при помощи функции `SN = SearchCount(Root);`, потом этот узел удаляется из дерева.

Comment: Я то-же так думал. Старательно все расписывал, комментировать, рисовал деревья на листочке. Не работает. А файл подгрузить не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ничего не удаляется, потому что функция `SearchCount()` всегда возвращает `NULL`. Она вызывается рекурсивно по левой ветке, пока не дойдет до `SC->left == NULL`. И кстати, если бы вы хоть раз прошли по программе дебаггером, вы бы это сразу увидели.

```
Node *SearchCount(Node *Root) 
{
    Node *SC = Root;
    if(SC == NULL) 
    { return SC; }
    else 
    {  
        ....
        return SearchCount(SC->left);
        return SearchCount(SC->right);
    }
}
```

Ну а уже в функции удаления, срабатывает условие на выход из нулевого дерева.

```
Node *RootDelete(Node *Root) {
    ....
    SN = SearchCount(Root); // !!! SN всегда == NULL
    if(SN == NULL) return NULL; // Дерево пустое
```

PS для тестирования работы программы заполняйте дерево вот так, без всяких файлов

```
int main()
{
    Root = AddNode(Root, "Number5");
    Root = AddNode(Root, "Number3");
    Root = AddNode(Root, "Number7");
    Root = AddNode(Root, "Number7");
```

Comment: Спасибо), вы очень помогли. Я не мог выкурить, почему удаляет первый элемент дерева, остальное оставляет как есть...

Comment: Вообще-то  она ничего не удаляет.   Спасибо здесь - принятый ответ! :) Нажмите галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: Это сейчас не удаляет))), до этого вариант был - удалял первый элемент.